# multiplying by 1.0 or 1.00 when dividing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to understand the exact difference between my code below,

```
count(CASE WHEN action = 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 1.0 / count(action) as perc

count(CASE WHEN action = 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 1.00 / count(action) as perc
```

When I test both give me same answer, but I have also seen it written both ways so wanted to know to be precise if there was any difference? Thank you

Comment: They are identical. 1.0 == 1.00 == 1.000 == 1.0000 == 1.00000...... you are using a decimal to force implicit cast to decimal from integer division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same essentially. The decimal precision will make no difference.